# Why PHP code for gives a notice for $_REQUEST global variable?

Tags: php, request, notice

```
<html>
    <body>

    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
        Name: <input type="text" name="fname">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>

    <?php
        $name = $_REQUEST['fname'];//Notice is coming at this line
        echo $name;
    ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

The above code shows Notice like this:-

```
Notice: Undefined index: fname in C:\xampp\htdocs\Programs\request.php on line 10
```

How to remove this error? I took this code from w3schools.com. 
It is running fine in w3schools.com site. In my PC also it runs but when I open this program in my browser, it shows the above line.
Plz help me..

Comment: Change `$name = $_REQUEST['fname'];` to `$name = isset($_REQUEST['fname'])?$_REQUEST['fname']:'Not Set';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP gives notice when variable are not defined like in your case `$_REQUEST['fname']` is not set/defined.

Change to:

```
$name = isset($_REQUEST['fname']) ? $_REQUEST['fname'] : "";//better way
```

OR you can do

```
$name = @$_REQUEST['fname'];//this way notice or warnings are suppressed
```

Answer (score 2):

it gives this notice when `$_REQUEST['fname']` is not set.

Change:

```
$name = $_REQUEST['fname'];//Notice is coming at this line
```

to:

```
$name = isset($_REQUEST['fname']) ? $_REQUEST['fname'] : "";
```

you need to check that if it is set or not by [**`isset()`**][1]
[1]:https://www.php.net/isset